# Rpm building and spec file for single script

Tags: linux, rpm, yum

I need to copy init script to /etc/init.d/ and copy others scripts to /opt//. But I would like to do it as RPM package.

I found tutorial to deploy singe file.
Please check it: [rpm single file tutorial](http://computernetworkingnotes.com/package-management/build-a-simple-rpm-that-packages-a-single-file.html)

Can you explain me %install section ?
What does $RPM_BUILD_ROOT refer on, if installed script is in /opt/sample_rpm and not in $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/sample_rpm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` is a "virtual root directory". That is when you build a RPM package you need to form a complete layout of the package, with all paths like `/usr/lib/`, `/etc/`, or as in your case `/opt/<package>/`. But since an ordinary user doesn't have permissions to create files in those system directories (and this is good indeed!) one should create the file system hierarchy under `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` which usually resides in a temporary directory like `/tmp/<mypackage>-buildroot` or something similar:

So a packager creates `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/etc/`, `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/lib` and so on and then places all the files for the package into those directories.

Some RPM variants require explicit `BuildRoot: <somepath>` header in the spec to set `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` to a non-empty value, while other (including e.g. recent specs from Fedora/RedHat) have this header set implicitly.

All the operations to create package layout are performed in `%install` section of the spec, and actually `%install` is simply a shell script, you may do what you would usually do to create a set of files.

Then you need to specify all the files placed under `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` in the `%files` section, this time *without `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT`*!

See e.g. [this spec for Lua](https://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/lua.git/tree/lua.spec) to understand how the things are performed. All those `%{_bindir}` `%{_libdir}` and other rpm macros are just a portable replacements for `/usr/bin`, `/usr/lib/` etc directories. This approach allows for example to put x86-64 libraries under `/usr/lib64`, x86-32 ones - under `/usr/lib` and this all done from the same spec.

Answer (score 0):

A simple spec file, with a file list:

```
Summary:   None
Name:      
Version:   1.1.1
Release:   1
License:   GPL
Group:     None          
Packager:  Jerry Donut <jerry@donut.com>
BuildArchitectures: noarch
BuildRoot:

%description
No description

%files
/usr/local/bin/script.sh
```

... and you can just add your files in the same way.

As you can see, BuildRoot doesn't need to be specified!

---

Building your package as unprivileged user : `$ rpmbuild -bb package-name.spec`

Setting up the rpm build environment in `/home/<user-name>/`: post #13 here...
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/need-rpm-package-for-php-version-5-2-7-and-up-on-redhat-5-1-a-766486/#13